# Replace value in dictionary with nested values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries with same keys and nested lists as values:

```
dict_1 =   {'PickMeterEquipment': [['value', 'PB:PRICELIST', 'list', 'LeaseAccountingContracts'],['value', 'PICK_SKU10', 'propval', '._sku']],'GenericPickRule': [['propval', '_amEntitled', 'literal', '0'], ['propval', '_sku', 'value', 'PICK_SKU1'], ['propval', '_sku', 'value', 'PICK_SKU2']]}
dict_2 =  {'PickMeterEquipment': [['ITEM', 'ABC'],['ITEM', 'XYZ'],['CLASS', 'PQR']],'GenericPickRule': [['ITEM', 'ZHC2'], ['ITEM', 'ZHC3'], ['ITEM', 'ZHC4']]}
```

Now I want to replace values in `dict_1` based on this condition:

`if '._sku' in dic1_1 : replace with corresponding dict_2 item`

AND

`if '_sku' in dic1_1 : replace with corresponding dict_2 item`

For example I need my Final output to be like this:

`OUTPUT: {PickMeterEquipment: [ everything same],['value', 'PICK_SKU10', 'propval', 'ABC'],[.....,PICK_SKU10', 'propval', 'XYZ']...]..}`

I am able to iterate over these two dicts but not able to replace values as there can be multiple values to be replaced and I need to make a new copy of that particular value.

```
#loop to iterate over two dicts
for k, k2 in zip(prop_val_item_map,item_rule_attach_map):
    print(prop_val_item_map[k],item_rule_attach_map[k2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict_1 =   {'PickMeterEquipment': [['value', 'PB:PRICELIST', 'list', 'LeaseAccountingContracts'],['value', 'PICK_SKU10', 'propval', '._sku']],'GenericPickRule': [['propval', '_amEntitled', 'literal', '0'], ['propval', '_sku', 'value', 'PICK_SKU1'], ['propval', '_sku', 'value', 'PICK_SKU2']]}
dict_2 =  {'PickMeterEquipment': [['ITEM', 'ABC'],['ITEM', 'XYZ'],['CLASS', 'PQR']],'GenericPickRule': [['ITEM', 'ZHC2'], ['ITEM', 'ZHC3'], ['ITEM', 'ZHC4']]}
for i in dict_1:
    for value_1, value_2 in zip(dict_1[i], dict_2[i]):
        if "._sku" in value_1:
            value_1.remove("._sku")
            value_1.append(value_2[-1])
        if "_sku" in value_1:
            value_1.remove("_sku")
            value_1.append(value_2[-1])

print(dict_1)
```

Output:

```
{'PickMeterEquipment': [['value',
   'PB:PRICELIST',
   'list',
   'LeaseAccountingContracts'],
  ['value', 'PICK_SKU10', 'propval', 'XYZ']],
 'GenericPickRule': [['propval', '_amEntitled', 'literal', '0'],
  ['propval', 'value', 'PICK_SKU1', 'ZHC3'],
  ['propval', 'value', 'PICK_SKU2', 'ZHC4']]}
```